# Circular reference for Repository in Symfony 5

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony5

I try to follow this tutorial : https://www.thinktocode.com/2018/03/05/repository-pattern-symfony/.

It's suppose to help structure your Repository.

But when i get to this point :

```
final class ProductRepository
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManagerInterface
     */
    private $entityManager;

    /**
     * @var ObjectRepository
     */
    private $objectRepository;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->objectRepository = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Product::class);
    }
    
    public function find(int $productId): Product
    {
        $product = $this->objectRepository->find($productId);
        return $product;
    }

    public function findOneByTitle(string $title): Product
    {
        $product = $this->objectRepository
            ->findOneBy(['title' => $title]);
        return $product;
    }

    public function save(Product $product): void
    {
        $this->entityManager->persist($product);
        $this->entityManager->flush();
    }
}
```

And testing my Repository with this test case :

```
<?php

namespace App\Tests\Repository;

use App\Repository\ProductRepository;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase;

class ProductRepository_KernelTest extends KernelTestCase
{

    private ?ProductRepository $_productRepository;

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        $kernel = self::bootKernel();
        $this->_productRepository = self::$container->get(ProductRepository::class);
    }

    public function test_findAllProductNatByLabelForLabelEmptyReturnTenProduct()
    {
        dump($this->_productRepository->findAllProductsByLabel('AACIFEMINE'));
        die();
    }
}
```

It loop endlessly.

I think it's due to this code :

```
public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
{
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    $this->objectRepository = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Product::class); // <-----
}
```

As it call the ProductRepository constructor inside of this same constructor... So i guess it's why that loop

So I don't know. Is this tutorial just wrong or not up to date ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.thinktocode.com/2018/03/05/repository-pattern-symfony/#comment-4155200782

> Maciej,
>
> You are correct that in these example we are using 2 repositories. The
> object repository from doctrine inside our own custom repository. This
> allows use to be decoupled from doctrine's repository and still change
> this in the future. This means to not set your custom repository as
> the default repository in your entity.
>
> You can get rid of inject the object repository, and in so only be
> using 1 repository by implementing a BaseRepository class in which you
> create the basic findBy, findOneBy, createQueryBuilder yourself. Take
> a look at the EntityRepository in Doctrine/ORM. This might be a good
> follow up topic to go over in a future article to create a better
> solution then I suggested in here.